# iOs Unable to register using remote APNs and ipv6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, applet

Using the `APNS` with ipv4 everything works perfectly, but  when I connect the iphone to a wireless network IPV6 (NAT64) , the device do not receive notification and this methods is never called

- `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`
- `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError`

Our code  :

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)app {
    // Configure the user interactions first.
    [self configureUserInteractions];

   // Register for remote notifications.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

// Handle remote notification registration.
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app
        didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken {
    // Forward the token to your provider, using a custom method.
    [self enableRemoteNotificationFeatures];
    [self forwardTokenToServer:devTokenBytes];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app
        didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)err {
    // The token is not currently available.
    NSLog(@"Remote notification support is unavailable due to error: %@", err);
    [self disableRemoteNotificationFeatures];
}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to Reachibility, have you tested your server for IPV6 compatibility?

Comment: The communication between the application ( iOs)  and the backend ( j2ee/spring) app  is happening correctly. but without  the Token (push id) , this method is never invoked  didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken .